# preg_match_all output all h tags with type

Tags: php, preg-match-all

i want to create a table of all the h tags for a specific page (seo reasons) and populate a table with them.

```
        $str = file_get_contents($Url);
        if(strlen($str)>0){
            preg_match_all(" /<(h\d*)>(\w[^<]*)/i",$str,$headings);

            foreach ($headings as $val) {
                echo "type: " . $val[1] . "\n";
                echo "content: " . $val[2] . "\n";
            }
        }
```

at the moment i am just echoing them out and getting weird results this is my first time ever using regular expressions so i figured its prob something wrong there.

also if someone knows of a good tutorial on handling the array preg_match_all returns that would be great.

Comment: First you shouldn't use regex to parse html/xml etc. unless your life somehow depends on it. Secondly I have no idea what "type" means? Could you provide concrete input and desired output?

Comment: sorry type is the kind of h tag (h1, h2, h3 etc) i want a table type and content(the actual text) what should i use?

Comment: You are just missing `PREG_SET_ORDER` as fourth parameter to `preg_match_all`.

Comment: thanks heaps mario can you post the code so i can mark as answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex was already working fine. But `preg_match_all` returns the result arrays typically ordered by match groups.  You can however add the `PREG_SET_ORDER` flag as fourth parameter to [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all), which is how your foreach expects it:

```
preg_match_all("/<(h\d*)>(\w[^<]*)/i",$str,$headings, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Btw, this is a perfectly legitimate use (and unlikely to fail) use of regular expressions, if we can assume you are working on your own applications output to add an headline table.

Answer (score 3):

Use this method to return an associative array with the Heading Tags, their types and instances:

```
public function getHeadingTags()
{
    preg_match_all( "#<h(\d)[^>]*?>(.*?)<[^>]*?/h\d>#i", 
                    $this->html, 
                    $matches,
                    PREG_PATTERN_ORDER
                  );
    $headings = array();
    foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $heading_key) {
        $headings["h$heading_key"][] = $matches[2][$key];
    }

    ksort($headings);
    return $headings;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to know more about regular expressions, you better buy a good book.
Or just google for good tutorials. Personally I like [`regular-expressions.info`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

All the information about `preg_match_all` function can be found at official documentation [`here`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php). PHP community usually share some useful code at manual pages, I believe you can find there any information you want.

```
php > $ch = curl_init('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883392/preg-match-all-output-all-h-tags-with-type');                                              
php > curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); $data = curl_exec($ch);
php > preg_match_all("!<h(\d)[^>]*>(.*?)</h\\1>!ism",$data,$headings);
php > var_export($headings);
array (                     
  0 =>                      
....  
2 =>
  array (
    0 => '<a href="/questions/7883392/preg-match-all-output-all-h-tags-with-type" class="question-hyperlink">preg_match_all output all h tags with type</a>',
    1 => '',
    2 => '
            Know someone who can answer?
            Share a <a href="/q/7883392">link</a> to this question via
            <a href="mailto:?subject=Stack%20Overflow%20Question&amp;body=preg_match_all%20output%20all%20h%20tags%20with%20type%0Ahttp%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fq%2f7883392">email</a>,
            <a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fq%2f7883392&amp;text=preg_match_all%20output%20all%20h%20tags%20with%20type">twitter</a>, or
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fq%2f7883392&amp;t=preg_match_all%20output%20all%20h%20tags%20with%20type">facebook</a>.
        ',
    3 => 'Your Answer',
    4 => '
            Browse other questions tagged <a href="/questions/tagged/php" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged \'php\'" rel="tag">php</a> <a href="/questions/tagged/preg-match-all" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged \'preg-match-all\'" rel="tag">preg-match-all</a>
                or <a href="/questions/ask">ask your own question</a>.
        ',
    5 => 'Hello World!',
    6 => 'Related',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are parsing the entire HTML content of a page, I would recommend you try [PHP's DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php):

```
$str = file_get_contents($Url);

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str);           

$hs = array();
for($type=1; $type<6; $type++)
{
  $h_es = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h'.$type);
  foreach($h_es as $h)
  {
    $hs[] = array('type'=>$type, 'content'=>$h->textContent);
  }
}

print_r($hs);
```

Answer (score 0):

This method can also be used (for get all tags H).
I tested it and it works. 
Because I needed it myself.

```
$str = file_get_contents($Url);
preg_match_all("|<h+[1-6](.*?)<\/h[1-6]+>|", $str , $matches_h_tag);
 $h_tags = "";
for($i=0; $i <= count($matches_h_tag[0]); $i++){
$h_tags .= $matches_h_tag[0][$i]; 
}
 echo $h_tags;
```

simple and fast method for get all tags (h)